# Some items could not be downloaded from the Store

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, backup, restore

While I was restoring my iPhone from iCloud backup, I got a message:

> Restore Incomplete - Some items could not be downloaded from the Store. If they are on your computer, you can restore them by syncing with iTunes.

I understand that this can happen when the apps that were installed on my iPhone in the past are no longer available on App Store. All I want to know is which apps were not able to downloaded from the store. Is there any way that I can see the list of the apps that couldn't be downloaded in this restore?

I haven't backup the phone on my computer for years. I also have a developer account and XCode, if it concerns.

Comment: Have you tried looking at Updates->Purchased->Not on this Phone?

Comment: @StephenCollins I have. There are just too many apps in that list because I've used iPhone more than 6 years. And I believe that the list wouldn't show the apps that are no longer on the App Store.